# Variable is Changing without Me Touching it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a memory game, and I have a class called 'Button'.

```
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Memory Game')
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
tk.resizable(0, 0)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=600, bg='white', bd=0, 
highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
class Button:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.open = False
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(pos[0], pos[1], pos[0]+100, pos[1]+100, fill='blue')
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.action)
        print(self.pos)
        #The positions are what they're supposed to be as of now.
    def action(self, event):
        print(self.pos)
        #If you click on the screen, then the console prints out [300, 400] no matter what the actual position is.
        print(event.x, event.y) #Prints out coords of where the mouse clicked
        if event.x >= self.pos[0] and event.x <= self.pos[0] + 100:
            if event.y >= self.pos[1] and event.y <= self.pos[1]+100:
                self.canvas.coords(self.id, 1000, 1000, 1100, 1100)
                #Makes Button Disappear from Tkinter Window
button_pos = [[0, 100], [0, 200], [0, 300], [0, 400], [100, 100], [100, 200], [100, 300], [100, 400], [200, 100], [200, 200], [200, 300], [200, 400], [300, 100], [300, 200], [300, 300], [300, 400]]
//coordinates for the buttons
buttons = []
for x in range(16):
    buttons.append(Button(button_pos[x]))
```

If you run this and click on the screen, you will see that the position of the buttons is seemingly always [300,400], no matter what. Why does this happen? None of the buttons actually disappear except for the bottom right one.

Comment: `[300, 400]` is the last one in your list.

Comment: I've realized that, but shouldn't all the buttons respond to the click?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] so we can actually run this as you suggest? I can guess at the missing `from tkinter import *` at the top, `tk.mainloop()` at the bottom, and removing the first syntax error, but it still doesn't run after that.

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure the problem is that `self.canvas.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.action)`. Each button tries to bind button-1 for the entire canvas. So whoever comes last will win. If you want to bind the whole canvas, you need to do that _once_, and then add your own hit-testing inside that callback.

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than that—you've called `bind_all` instead of `bind`, so you're capturing button-1 for any widget anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
self.canvas.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.action)
```

Each button tries to take over all `Button-1` events for the entire canvas—in fact, because you're using `bind_all`, for all widgets anywhere in the app. So, each one steals the binding from the one before, and at the end, the last button gets all clicks.

What you want to do is have the *canvas* bind the button, then hit-test the click, and then pass it to the rectangle manually. For example, after all of your existing code (but before wherever you start the main loop), add this:

```
def action(event):
    item, = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    buttons[item-1].action(event)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", action)
```

And then remove the `self.canvas.bind_all` line. Now, the canvas gets its own clicks, finds the closest shape to the click (which will be a one-based index to your rectangles in the order of creation), and dispatches the event manually.

Comment: That doesn't work. It says list index out of range. I tried to print `item`, and it gives a number like 33

Comment: @AnshGupta It works when I run it with your code as posted. But obviously your code as posted is not your actual code. If you're, say, inserting more shapes into the canvas before the rectangles, then they won't be #1-16. If you're doing something more complicated, store the rectangles in a dict with each one's `id` attribute as key, instead of in a list with the `id-1` as index.

Comment: I fixed it by using my own algorithm to find which button to move, but otherwise, I did everything you said. Thanks a lot for your help!